# req.body not working I can't receive data from POST with express in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

This is my first time building an express server in nodeJS, i don't know much of what im doing but i managed to make POSTs and GETs using routes and controllers... I don't know why req.body is showing {} on terminal, obviously im not receiving any data from the AJAX, but why? please help.

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const path = require("path");
const mysql = require('mysql');
const myConnection = require('express-myconnection');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// Manejar solicitudes JSON
app.use(express.json());


// Configuración de acceso a la base de datos
const hostDB = "localhost";
const userDB = "root";
const passwordDB = "";
const portDB = 3306;
const databaseDB = 'motionpose';

// Importación de rutas
const usuarioRuta = require('./routes/usuarios');
const registroRuta = require('./routes/registroRuta');
// Configuración
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5555);

// Middlewares
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(myConnection(mysql, {
    host: hostDB,
    user: userDB,
    password: passwordDB,
    port: portDB,
    database: databaseDB
}, 'single'));

// Rutas
app.use('/login', usuarioRuta); 
app.use('/registro', registroRuta);
// Archivos estáticos
app.use(express.static('public'));

// API
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'view', 'index.html'))
}); 

app.listen(app.get('port'), ()=>{
    console.log('Server corriendo en puerto: ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

usuarios.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // Importa body-parser
const usuariosController = require('../controllers/usuariosController');

router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.get('/', usuariosController.view);
router.post('/', usuariosController.post);
module.exports = router;
```

login.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $("#continuarBoton").on("click", function(){
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("correo", $("#correo").val());
        formData.append("contrasena", $("#contrasena").val());
        $.ajax({
            url: '/login', // Reemplaza con la ruta correcta hacia tu función getUsuarios
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                correo: "test1",
                contrasena: "test2"
            },
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if(data.Exito){
                    console.log("Solicitud POST exitosa");
                }else{
                    console.error("Solicitud POST DENEGADA");
                }
                
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

usuariosController.js

```
const controller = {};
const path = require('path');
let usuariosLista = [];
let Exito;
controller.view = (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'view', 'login.html'));
    Exito = true;
};
controller.post = (req, res) => {
    console.log("This is working");
    console.log(req.body);
    res.json({Exito: Exito});
}

module.exports = controller;
```

Terminal output:

```
This is working
{}
POST /login 200 3.802 ms - 14
```

Im expecting to console.log the data from AJAX.
Im receiving {} when printing req.body or undefined when I try to access an specific value, for example req.body.correo.

I already installed body-parser.

Comment: Consider [not using jQuery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#post); it did a great job a couple of decades ago when native browser APIs weren't very good, but times have changed.

Comment: You are right, but i already know how to use jquery and learning pure javascript makes me very lazy, but I will do it one day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> ```
> router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
> router.use(bodyParser.json());
> ```

So `req.body` will be populated if you get a request where the data is encoded as either JSON or with URL Form Encoding **and** the request has a `Content-Type` header that matches.

---

Then you said:

> ```
> data: {
>     correo: "test1",
>     contrasena: "test2"
> },
> ```

You are passing an **object** to jQuery.

Under **normal** circumstances it would encoded it as URL Form Encoded data **and** set the correct content-type.

---

However you also said:

> ```
> processData: false,
> ```

… which tells jQuery not to process the value passed to `data` so it hits the underlying `XMLHttpRequest` object and is converted to the string `[object Object]` (which is useless).

You also said:

> ```
> contentType: false,
> ```

… which tells jQuery not to set the content-type and let `XMLHttpRequest` figure it out (which it will set to `text/plain`).

**Remove those two parameters**.

---

If you wanted to send JSON then you'd need to:

- Pass JSON to `data`
- Set the content-type explicitly

```js
    data: JSON.stringify({
        correo: "test1",
        contrasena: "test2"
    }),
    contentType: 'application/json',
```

You *still* shouldn't set `processData: false,` as jQuery doesn't do processing of strings in the first place.

---

*Aside*

> I already installed body-parser.

Don't do that.

Express has a dependency on body-parser and exposes it though the express object. Let it manage which version of body-parser you use instead of doing it manually.

Use [`express.json`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json) and [`express.urlencoded`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.urlencoded) instead.

Comment: Friend, you are a lifesaver, you were exactly right about the ajax query, in fact I had copied that ajax from another older project, because I had forgotten about the structure and it was just those lines bothering me, thank you very much.